# Wordpress Internet Explorer 11 issue

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

Has anybody ever experienced this strange issue with wordpress in IE?
The title and the description of the slider on my site [implanttimatkat.fi](https://implanttimatkat.fi)
has moved to he left of the screen. On all the other major browsers they are on the middle, as they should be. I did not change the css of the child-theme and wondering why this has happened. I'm using IE 11 for testing.

CSS

```
.carousel-caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    top: 25%;
    max-width: 670px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the css which is not working in IE. In the meantime I found the solution. margin: auto will not center with max-width value. I have changed the max-width to width, now the caption centers in IE as well.